# Vote duplicate for Gold tag badge when I added tag myself, shows HTML content in message

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, popup

I just voted duplicate on a question and got this popup.  Why is it showing HTML tags?

Note: I know what the popup is for, and why I got the popup is not the issue here.  The HTML content in the popup is the issue.

The issue:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up to our attention, we're still tracking all of these down. It was introduced due to a security fix we implemented a while back.

This one has been fixed! Please let us know if anything else comes up.

Appreciate the help!